# JFrame closes immediately

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, pong

I am attempting to make a pong game but every time I try to launch it to test the buffer strategy, it immediately closes. I tried resolving this by adding a start and stop synchronized void, but it did not seem to work. Normally this kind of thing can be easy to fixed but I am baffled.

```
package pong;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

JFrame frame; //game window stuff
public final int WIDTH = 400; 
public final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
public final Dimension gameSize = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
public final String TITLE =  "Pong InDev";

BufferedImage Image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

static boolean gameRunning = false; //Is game running?
public void run() {

    while (gameRunning) {
        tick();
        render();
    }
 }
    //attempted to fix problem
    public synchronized void start1() {
    gameRunning = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
    System.exit(0);
    //End start method
  }
  public static synchronized void stop() {
    gameRunning = false;
    //End stop method
}

public Game() {
    frame = new JFrame();

    setPreferredSize(gameSize);
    setMinimumSize(gameSize);
    setMaximumSize(gameSize);

    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle(TITLE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }

public void tick() {
}


public void render() {
BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
if(bs == null) {
     createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}

Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

g.drawImage(Image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

g.dispose();
bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start1();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.exit(0)` at the end of the start method looks like the culprit.  Try removing it.

Comment: Yes, end of `start1` method. I think that is it.

Comment: Thanks, I am a giant noob when it comes to java

Comment: No sweat - I can't tell the number of times just having someone else look at my code has saved a bunch of time tracking down a mistake.